# FindMinimum: How can I know which method Mathematica has used?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I have been using FindMinimum to find a local minimum of a non-linear function within a constrained region.

How can I know which method Mathematica has selected to find the local minimum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, the *practical* answer is that you can't really find that out easily. However, you *can* specify which method to use. If you need to know what method is being used, I suggest you select the method yourself. There is a lot of helpful information on how to control methods in this tutorial: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html

Answer (score 11):

Excerpt from [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) of Mathematica:

> - With Method->Automatic and two starting values, FindMinimum uses
>     Brent's principal axis method. With one starting value for each
>     variable, FindMinimum uses BFGS quasi-Newton methods, with a limited
>     memory variant for large systems.
> - If the function to be minimized
>     is a sum of squares, FindMinimum uses the Levenberg–Marquardt method
>     (Method->"LevenbergMarquardt").
> - With constraints, FindMinimum uses
>     interior point methods.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I have a value for each variable and I have constraints, so I guess it uses interior point methods. Is there any way to know which one ? I need to know the exact method, since I have to report the method used.

Comment: There is a description of the Interior Point algorithm given on the reference side: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#442312913

Answer (score 5):

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) the `Method` that produces the [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) result as `Automatic`

```
Select[{#, 
     FindMinimum[Abs[x + 1] + Abs[x + 1.01] + Abs[y + 1], {x, y}, 
       Method -> #] // Quiet} & /@ {"Gradient", "ConjugateGradient", 
    "InteriorPoint", "QuasiNewton", "Newton", "LinearProgramming", 
    "QuadraticProgramming", "LevenbergMarquardt"}, #[[2]] == 
    FindMinimum[Abs[x + 1] + Abs[x + 1.01] + Abs[y + 1], {x, y}, 
     Method -> Automatic] &] // Quiet

(* {{"QuasiNewton", {0.01, {x -> -1.00683, y -> -1.}}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just used your code and got the empty set. I just replaced your function by mine and added the constraints and the initial point.

Comment: @Maria - Without your function, constraints, and initial point, I cannot tell you what is going on. Recommend that you **edit your question** to include this information. Assuming that some random number is needed in the method used, you would need to use [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) to force the same random number.