# Automatic Method for FindMinimum with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

What is the default method used by `FindMinimum` with constraints?

The documentation says:

> "Currently, the only method available for constrained optimization is the interior point algorithm"

However, a random example gives different results for the `Method -> Automatic` and `Method -> "InteriorPoints"`:

```
Reap[
  FindMinimum[
    {x^2 + y^2, 
     (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, 
    {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
    Method -> Automatic,
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]
  ]
]

Reap[
  FindMinimum[
    {x^2 + y^2, 
     (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, 
    {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
    Method -> "InteriorPoint", 
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]
  ]
]
```

The above code yields the same final solution but the steps taken are different for each, which suggests that the interior points method is not actually the default one in this case.

The same question has been asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/how-to-find-which-automatic-method-is-used-by-findminimum?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181266/findminimum-how-can-i-know-which-method-mathematica-has-used)

So what is the exact method being used when `Method -> Automatic` is specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SystemOptions["FindMinimumOptions"]
```

> ```
> {"FindMinimumOptions" -> 
>    {"DefaultInteriorPointMethod" -> "IPOPT", 
>     "TreatQuadraticProgramming" -> 0}}
> ```

```
Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
       Method -> "IPOPT", StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]] == 
 Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x,   4}, {y, 4}}, 
       Method -> Automatic, StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We can also use `"IPOPT"` as the value for `"Method"` suboption of the option `Method`:

```
Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
   Method -> Automatic, StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]] == 
 Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "Method" -> "IPOPT"}, StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Using the option setting `Method -> {Automatic, "Method" -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"}` gives the same result as `Method -> "InteriorPoint"`:

```
Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
    Method -> "InteriorPoint", StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]] == 
 Reap[FindMinimum[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 1)^2 + 2 (y - 1)^2 > 5}, {{x, 4}, {y, 4}}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "Method" -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"}, 
   StepMonitor :> Sow[{x^2 + y^2, x, y}]]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: @kglr.....Great! thank you.... Can I understand IPOPT and NonlinearInteriorPoint as just variants of the Interior point implementation? Where can I learn about the difference between both these options?

Comment: @VarunM, for `IPOPT` see the tutorial [Optimizing With IPOPT](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/IPOPTLink/tutorial/OptimizingWithIPOPT.html) and the guide [IPOPTLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/IPOPTLink/guide/IPOPTLink.html).  For `"NonlinearInteriorPoint"` I don't know of any reference.